# `infer`: simulation-based null distribution of the standard deviation is not centered around the null hypothesis

Tags: r, statistics, type-inference

When using `infer` the test hypotheses about the standard deviation I realized that the simulation-based null distribution is never centered around the null hypothesis:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)

data <- tibble(x = rnorm(100, mean = 2, sd = 1))

data %>%
  specify(response = x) %>%
  hypothesise(null = "point", sigma = 5) %>%
  generate(reps = 1000, type = "bootstrap") %>%
  calculate("sd") %>%
  visualise()
```

I have investigated the source code and did not find any transformation done to generate the null distribution, is there something I am understanding wrong?

As the simulated data is normal I was expecting something close to the parametric test (changed for standard deviation instead of variance):

```r
ggplot(NULL, aes(x = sqrt(rchisq(1000, 99)/(99)*(5)^2))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 15, color = "white") +
  labs(
    x = "stat",
    y = "count"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the bootstrap.  You're using a dataset for the bootstrap that itself does not have a standard deviation of 2 (it's close, but not exact).  Since you're drawing with replacement from a sample that doesn't have sd of 2, the average sd will not be 2.  Here's an example.  Note that the data have a standard deviation of 1.83 and that is around where the histogram is centred.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)
set.seed(207)
data <- tibble(x = rnorm(100, mean = 2, sd = 2))
sd(data$x)
#> [1] 1.832712
data %>%
  specify(response = x) %>%
  hypothesise(null = "point", sigma = 5) %>%
  generate(reps = 1000, type = "bootstrap") %>%
  calculate("sd") %>%
  visualize()
```

[image]

Below, we can transform the data so the data themselves have a standard deviation of exactly 2, then you will get the expected answer in the histogram.

```r
data$x <- data$x * 2/sd(data$x)
sd(data$x)
#> [1] 2
data %>%
  specify(response = x) %>%
  hypothesise(null = "point", sigma = 5) %>%
  generate(reps = 1000, type = "bootstrap") %>%
  calculate("sd") %>%
  visualize()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

#### Answering Comments

In the comment, OP asked why this works for the mean, but not the SD.  The `generate()` function calls the `bootstrap()` function for `type = "bootstrap"`, as in the example.  In `bootstrap()`, there is the following code:

```r
    if (identical(attr(attr(x, "params"), "names"), 
        "mu")) {
        col <- response_name(x)
        x[[col]] <- x[[col]] - mean(x[[col]], na.rm = TRUE) + 
          attr(x, "params")
```

When you specify `mu` in the hypothesize, the `"params"` attribute is named `mu` with the null hypothesized value.  `x` - the variable being bootstrapped - then has the null hypothesized mean imposed on it before it gets resampled in the bootstrap.  So, in essence, when the mean is being bootstrapped, the function does what I did by hand in my answer - impose the null hypothesis value.  When you hypothesize `sigma`, no such thing is done. It skips over the check for mean and median and then just resamples from the data.  So, if your data do not have the null distribution attribute (e.g., sd=2), then you won't get the right answer.  This seems like an oversight on the part of the package authors.  However, you could fix this by simply imposing the null condition on the data in the pipeline before `generate()` is called.

Comment: What I don't understand is the fact that when I use `hypothesise` the package says that what is generate is the null distribution. If I do it for the mean, for example, the simulate null distribution is centred about the mean of the hypothesis (I am unfortunately still not allowed to post images) and I was expected the same to happen for the standard deviation...

Comment: @2p4olE3xjEQJ I added a discussion at the bottom of my answer.  I think you're right about how it should work, but I explain why it doesn't in fact work like that.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: I reported the bug to the package maintainer; you can follow the issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/tidymodels/infer/issues/523).